# Extract Text After a String

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data table that look like this:

```
ID   RESULT
1    blah blah asc rdsd Critical Care Time : 3,342 job ded...
2    apple asc red Critical Care Time : 322 ED none...
3    computer Critical Care Time : 7,777 cul ninea....
```

I want to extract the time amount after "Critical Care Time :" to make a new column so the database reads:

```
ID   RESULT                                                     Minutes
1    blah blah asc rdsd Critical Care Time : 3,342 job ded...   3,342
2    apple asc red Critical Care Time : 322 ED none...          322
3    computer Critical Care Time : 7,777 cul ninea....          7,777
```

I have code that looks like this but its still extracting all next after the minutes:

```
DF['Minutes'] = DF.RESULT.str.extract(r'Critical Care Time : \s*([^\.]*)\s*\ ', expand=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
df["Minutes"] = df["RESULT"].str.extract(r"Critical Care Time :\s*([\d.,]+)")
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   ID                                                    RESULT Minutes
0   1  blah blah asc rdsd Critical Care Time : 3,342 job ded...   3,342
1   2         apple asc red Critical Care Time : 322 ED none...     322
2   3         computer Critical Care Time : 7,777 cul ninea....   7,777
```